# Mockito.When method not able to return mocked object when the method is called

Tags: java, spring, junit, jdbctemplate

I see lot of posts on this question but still not able to solve my problem.

```
when(queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources(anyString(), refEq(filterDto), anyString(), anyString(),
                anyInt(), anyInt(), anyString())).thenReturn(tenantResponseDto);
TenantResponseDto dto = queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources(anyString(), refEq(filterDto),
                anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyString());
```

When i debug the object. I'm not able to see the mock data in it. is there anything which I am missing?

Below one is my TestClass:

```
    public class QueryEngineAPITest extends AbstractTest {

    QueryEngineService queryEngineService = Mockito.mock(QueryEngineService.class);
    TenantResponseDto tenantResponseDto;

    private QueryEngineDto queryEngineDto;
    private RelationshipFilterDto filterDto;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        prepareMockData();

    }

    void prepareMockData() {
        tenantResponseDto = new TenantResponseDto();
        int i = 0;
        queryEngineDto = new QueryEngineDto();
        List<Map<String, Object>> mockDataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        while (i < 10) {
            Map<String, Object> mockDataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            mockDataMap.put("APPLICATION", "AWS");
            mockDataMap.put("ENVIRONMENT_NAME", "SIGMA LABS" + i);
            mockDataList.add(mockDataMap);
            i++;
        }
        queryEngineDto.setQueryData(mockDataList);
        tenantResponseDto.setResponseAsQueryEngineDto(queryEngineDto);
tenantResponseDto.setResponseCount(Long.valueOf(queryEngineDto.getQueryData().size()));

    filterDto = new RelationshipFilterDto();
    filterDto.setBefore("");
}

@Test
public void getRelationShipsTest() throws Exception {
    when(queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources(eq(""), refEq(filterDto), eq(""), eq(""), eq(1), eq(1),
            eq(""))).thenReturn(tenantResponseDto);
    TenantResponseDto dto = queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources(eq(""), refEq(filterDto), eq(""),
            eq(""), eq(1), eq(1), eq(""));
    assertFalse(dto.getResponseAsQueryEngineDto().getQueryData().isEmpty());
    assertEquals(Long.valueOf(dto.getResponseAsQueryEngineDto().getQueryData().size()), Long.valueOf(10));

}
```

Comment: What means `when i debug`? Does your test fail? Or do you have any error stacktrace?

Comment: Assertions are failing. With the data i provided as mock

Comment: `queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources("", filterDto,
                "", "", 0, 0, "")` - try to use data and not argmatchers

Comment: Still same. I'm getting null

Comment: You should attach full your test code to see used variables `filterDto` and `tenantResponseDto`

Comment: Please check now Alex I've updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232770/discussion-between-ufo-rider-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mocked method with arguments doesn't match method you are calling

```
when(queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources(eq(""), refEq(filterDto), eq(""), eq(""), eq(1), eq(1),eq(""))).thenReturn(tenantResponseDto);
TenantResponseDto dto = queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources(eq(""), refEq(filterDto), eq(""),
                eq(""), eq(1), eq(1), eq(""));
```

You need to change second line to:

```
TenantResponseDto dto = queryEngineService.getRelationshipWithResources("",filterDto, "", "", 1, 1, "");
```

`eq` and `refEq` are called argument matchers, when you want to run test you need to provide arguments as they are, not in argument matcher